# How to stop the VSCode CI servers from retrying 1400 times

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

This question seem wrong for S.O. to me but [the Visual Studio Code team told me to ask it here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/100062) so I'm asking it here.

I forked [the vscode repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/), made a branch called dev, pushed it to stack overflow, and proceeded to get over 1400 emails from the VSCode CI over the next 5 days.

[image]

My phone was buzzing every few minutes with notifications about new emails from the CI which I never personally signed up for. All I did was make a branch called 'dev'.

How do I stop the VSCode's servers from retying 1400 times?

Comment: If you can't turn of the mail sending add the sender to the kill list or spam filter of the email tool. Or create a custom email filter and move them over to the trash folder.

Comment: That's not a bad solution to the email problem but turning off the mail is not really the goal. The goal is to get it not to retry 1400 times and use 1400 times of computer resources / energy

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a [GitHub Action](https://github.com/features/actions), like one of the actions defined in [`microsoft/vscode/.github/workflows`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/master/.github/workflows)

Check if by deleting that folder (just for testing), you would still get the same emails.
Then you can add those actions back and see which one is the culprit.